# VisualSVN Server : get /svnindex.xsl forbidden while accessing from browser

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

We have configured the visualsvn server in remote machine, while accessing the repository from the browser in our local machine, we are getting the below error in the internet explorer browser

```
'The XML page cannot be displayed' 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and
then click the Refresh button, or try again later
```

In the server machine's Event viewer, we found the log 'get /svnindex.xsl forbidden'.

Please note that we are able to connect the repository in TortoiseSVN & other subversion command line tools.

Is any setup or permission is needed to browse the repository in the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account that runs VisualSVN Server service (the account is "Network Service" by default) must have Read & Execute permissions to `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%`. It seems that in your case the account does not have Read access to `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%htdocs` or `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%htdocs\svnindex.xsl`. Check the permissions in order to solve the issue.

Read the article [KB37: Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/) for more information.